# matrix derivative of an exponential function evaluated at a scalar

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

For $\frac{\partial }{\partial \beta} e^{(X_i \beta)}$

$X_i$ is a row vector, $\beta$ is a column vector so that the argument of e is a scalar.

I know the answer is

$ e^{(X_i \beta)}X'_i$

but why is the last row vector transposed into a column vector?

In addition what does it mean to take the derivative in this case with respect to the vector $\beta$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using, as example, $2-$dimension vectors:
$
X=(X_1,X_2)
$
and 
$
\beta=(\beta_1, \beta_2)^T
$
we have:
$$
e^{(X\beta)}=e^{(X_1\beta_1+X_2\beta_2)}
$$
and ( see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-vector) for the derivative of a scalar with respect to  a vector)
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}e^{(X\beta)}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_1}e^{(X_1\beta_1+X_2\beta_2)}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta_2}e^{(X_1\beta_1+X_2\beta_2)}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
X_1e^{(X_1\beta_1+X_2\beta_2)}\\
X_2e^{(X_1\beta_1+X_2\beta_2)}
\end{pmatrix}=
e^{(X\beta)}X^T
$$
I think that you can extend this to any finite $n-$dimension vectors.

Comment: I understand it now, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! And don't forget to accept if you like the answer :)